# User interface for addition/deletion of items to a list?

Tags: html

I have a ban list that I'm building as part of an application that displays articles. This ban list will contain keywords, which if found in an article, would lead to the article being disabled(the article will not be displayed on the front-end)

I'm having a tough time visualizing the UI. I could always display a textarea and ask the user to enter keywords comma separated and when they want to delete again the textarea will be presented and they can edit the entered keywords. But I find my idea very unfriendly to the user.

My question is how do I program the UI so that its easy to add new keywords. I also would like to be adviced on a nifty way showing the existing keywords and also deleting them.

This ban list will be part of the admin panel/backend and will be accessible only to the site administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many banned words will there be? If a handfull then your suggestion of a comma separated list makes sense - perhaps sorted alphabetically when re-presented for editing.

I speculate that the list could become quite extensive, and hence perhaps you would need to present several pages of excluded words. In which case, some form of paginated, alphabetic display, with a little (x) beside each entry to permit deletion.

And a separate entry field which would accept single words and add them into the list, displaying the relevent page might work.

One other thought: will your list contain profane or otherwise potentially offensive words? if is possible that representing the list could itself be offensive in some way? You may need to find a way to O??????e the O??????e. Which might present a few challenges.

Answer (score 1):

I would display them as a list, with a textfield at the top or bottom to add new ones. 
Add an icon to each to let the user delete it, and implement both adding and deletion by Ajax: then you can sort the list before redisplaying it. 
(Actually, you could do that all in the browser with Javascript and not use Ajax: in that case you'll have to pass the whole list to the server when it's needed).